# Most cost effective way to deploy iOS app with Xamarin with only a Mac?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a strong background in .Net and some Python. After years of PC work, my primary (only) machine at home is a Mac.

I have an idea for an iOS (and Android) app that would be a total labor-of-love, there is basically no monetization possible with it, but I still want to do it. What is the most cost effective way to deploy an app, with Xamarin and only using a Mac?

I will need a database to power the app. I know that I can use MS Azure for a pretty low cost but I know that Xamarin licensing for the SQL Data library is a total budget killer. I know that I could expose web services, but that would require writing the web services with .NET and I want to do this project exclusively on a Mac.

So what are the database options? Can I hook Xamarin directly to MySQL? Can someone please provide sample code for connecting from Xamarin to MySQL? What are some of the better MySQL only providers? I wouldn't need a web host, just DB.

Are there any other potential costs/licenses that I'm overlooking?

Comment: What about Core Data? While not database per se (rather, an object graph management), it can be used to persist large amounts of data.

Comment: I assume he means a server side database.  If he just needs local storage, he can use SQLite

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry that I didn't clarify that. It needs to be a server database, distributed to all users.

Answer (score 3):

You never want to expose your database directly to a mobile client.  You always want to have some sort of service brokering your db requests to the outside world.

If your client is simple enough that it will fit under the app size limit, you can use Xamarin's free tier.  Otherwise you can use the Indie tier.  You should not need the business tier.  If this is something that might be a workable open source project, I believe you might be able to ask Xamarin to donate a license.

You will also need an Apple developer license, $99/year, for deployment.

You can use MSSQL, Azure, MySQL, etc to power the server side db.  You can write webservices with ASP.NET, PHP, Ruby, etc - there is no reason the server side has to be .NET unless that is what works best for you.  You can run a VM on the Mac and run VS2013 Express for ASP.NET, or do it directly from the Mac with Xamarin Studio (not sure exactly what level of support there is for this under Mono, but it is doable).  Most of the other options can be written natively in OS X.

Other than the Mac hardware, the only other absolute expense is $99 for the Apple Developer account.

Answer (score 1):

For web services on a Mac with C#, look into v3 branch of ServiceStack. There is also ServiceStack.OrmLite which is a database client (MySQL, SQLite, SQL Server etc), it has a SQLite implementation which will run on the local machine (mobile) with Xamarin.iOS & Xamarin.Android.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need this to be a distributed database

Comment: Either you will distribute a SQLite file or you sync the local SQLite file from the server using web services. You are not going to run a server database engine on a mobile device, it doesn't make sense. Syncing the clients with ServiceStack components is extremely easy.